# Check if batch argument is empty not working

Tags: batch-file

I'm not sure what i'm missing here, but passing arguments the script still using the :NONE Option?

Actual script:

```
@ECHO off
CLS
ECHO.
:: DO NOT EDIT THE FOLLOWING LINES
SET ARG=%1
IF "%ARG%"=="-commit" GOTO COMMIT
IF "%ARG%"=="-checkout" GOTO CHECKOUT
IF "%ARG%"=="-tag" GOTO TAG
IF "%ARG%"=="" GOTO NONE

:CHECKOUT
ECHO checkout
GOTO DONE

:TAG
ECHO reserve tag
GOTO DONE

:COMMIT
ECHO commit
GOTO DONE

:DONE
ECHO Done!

:NONE
ECHO argument not valid
```

Test results:

Result of  :`test.bat -tag` **[ NOK ]**

```
reserve tag
Done!
argument not valid
```

Result of  :`test.bat` **[ OK ]**

```
argument not valid
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your :NONE is following your :DONE, so after it finishes in DONE it will just continue in the program, going right to NONE, making it look like there is an error.
edit: someone beat me to it, Joey's answer is correct!

Answer (score 3):

Batch file control flow is from top to bottom, barring any `goto`s. Control flow continues after `echo Done!` because you don't jump elsewhere. Thus it includes the following lines.

You may want to add `goto :eof` after `echo Done!`, which jumps to the end of the batch file (it's a special syntax, you don't need to provide a `:eof` label). Otherwise you could reorder the `:DONE` and `:NONE` labels (but then you'd get a »Done!« after »argument not valid«).

Comment: I forgot about batch flow :), That's what happen when you develop in python for 5h and suddenly you go to batch scripting hehe, Thanks!